# How to write out percentage of file copying using Binary Stream?

Tags: java

I want to show the percentage while copying file by using binary stream but I don't know the way, that How to do it?

Below is my code.

```
public static void binaryStream() throws IOException {

    try {

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("Untitled.png"));
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("Untitled-copied.png"));

        int data;
        while ((data = inputStream.read()) >= 0) {
            outputStream.write(data);
        }

        outputStream.write(data);

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to calculate / get the size of the file to be copied and then track the progress of the copying by counting the bytes already read&written and divide that byteCount by the size.

Comment: first get the file size, later meanwhile copying use buffer size to write and by this you can get the divide value of percentage.

Comment: You should look at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html   you can combine with AtomicInteger and poll an AtomicInteger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of how to do it like other people mentioned in the comments.

```
import java.io.*;

public class BinaryStream {
    public static void binaryStream(String file1, String file2) throws Exception
    {
      File sourceFile = new File(file1);
      try(
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile); 
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(file2))
      ) {
        long lenOfFile = sourceFile.length();

        long currentBytesWritten = 0;
        int data;
        while ((data = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
          outputStream.write(data);
          currentBytesWritten += 1;
          System.out.printf("%2.2f%%%n",
              100*((double)currentBytesWritten)/((double)lenOfFile));
        }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      binaryStream("Untitled.png", "Untitled-copied.png");
   }
}
```

Note that I've made some changes:

1. Removed the extra outputStream.write() call you had that was writing extra content incorrectly
2. Using try-with-resources idiom to close the streams you open even on exceptions
3. Throw the exceptions instead of catching, as you shouldn't catch them if you can't handle them
4. Compare to `-1`, as that is the documented value for end of file (end of stream)

Output is like this on my computer:

```
0,06%
// removed data
99,89%
99,94%
100,00%
```

Note also that this code will print something after each byte written, so it is *highly* inefficient. You might want to do that less often. On that note, you're reading and writing one byte at a time, which is also very inefficient - you might want to use [read(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) instead, reading in chunks. Example of that, using 256 byte array:

```
import java.io.*;

public class BinaryStream {
  public static void binaryStream(String file1, String file2) throws Exception {
    File sourceFile = new File(file1);
    try(
      FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
      FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(file2))
    ) {
      long lenOfFile = sourceFile.length();
      long bytesWritten = 0;
      int amountOfBytesRead;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

      while ((amountOfBytesRead = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, amountOfBytesRead);
        bytesWritten += amountOfBytesRead;
        System.out.printf("%2.2f%%%n",
            100*((double)bytesWritten)/((double)lenOfFile));
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    binaryStream("Untitled.png", "Untitled-copied.png");
  }
}
```

Output on my computer:

```
14,69%
29,37%
44,06%
58,75%
73,44%
88,12%
100,00%
```

Note that in the first example, return value of .read() is actually the byte that was read, whereas in the second example, return value of .read() is the *amount* of bytes read and the actual bytes go into the byte array.

Comment: This is good solution, except one thing: copy files and progress bar value calulation should be in a different threads.

Comment: Do you have some specific educational purpose for that double-casting expression? I would trust a simple ```100.0*bytesWritten/lenOfFile``` (and then it is visibly a decimal -more precisely, ```double```- calculation, and without cryptic 100d or 100f notation)

Comment: @tevemadar I think that's a matter of preference, I like to make required casts like that explicit.

Comment: Sorry about the strange order of events. Originally I modified the try-with-resource constructs (they correctly handle multiple resources in a single ```try```, see 3rd snippet: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) when I added the comment, also fixing indentation, and an "irregular" opening bracket somewhere. Then I submitted it for review. Then I noticed the horizontal scrollbar in the first block, and considered adding a line break, but I cancelled instead, apparently cancelling the whole edit, not just the line-break.